# Getting error in GEE while computing PAR from ERA5 insolation data

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

The error states:

```
- Scaled Cumulative Max Insolation Bands: Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with incompatible bands was encountered:
  First image type: 1 bands ([scaled_cumulative_max_insolation_00_to_15]).
Current image type: 1 bands ([scaled_cumulative_max_insolation_15_to_30]).
          Image ID: 1
Some bands might require explicit casts.
```

The problem area of the code:

```
// Create bands for each 15-day interval (e.g., Nov 1 - Nov 15, Nov 16 - Nov 30, etc.)
var intervals = ee.List.sequence(0, 180, 15); // Adjust the intervals as needed
var cumulativeMaxInsolationBands = intervals.map(function(intervalStart) {
  var intervalEnd = ee.Number(intervalStart).add(15);
  var intervalMean = scaledCumulativeMaxInsolation
    .clip(table)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), table.geometry(), 1000)
    .get('cumulative_max_insolation');

  var bandName = ee.String('scaled_cumulative_max_insolation_')
    .cat(ee.Number(intervalStart).format('%02d'))
    .cat('_to_')
    .cat(ee.Number(intervalEnd).format('%02d'));

  var bandImage = scaledCumulativeMaxInsolation
    .select(['cumulative_max_insolation'])
    .rename(bandName)
    .set('interval_start', ee.Date(intervalStart).format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
    .set('interval_end', ee.Date(intervalEnd).format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
    .set('interval_mean', intervalMean);

  return bandImage;
});

// Convert the list to an ImageCollection
var cumulativeMaxInsolationCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(cumulativeMaxInsolationBands);

// Print the result to the console
print(cumulativeMaxInsolationCollection);
```

How do I resolve the issue?

I am not great with code.